# Seeking open source location allocation modeling software

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis, location-allocation

I'm looking for open source tools for location allocation modelling (eg planning public health facilities).  Preferably in a GIS environment.  I know GRASS somewhat, but v.net.alloc doesn't seem to take account of demand.

I don't know if SAGA or Sextante have something.

Answer (score 4):

You could try Flowmap. It is specially designed to analyse flow patterns.

You can find it here: http://flowmap.geog.uu.nl/

Answer (score 2):

1. maxcovr package in R: https://github.com/njtierney/maxcovr. This package implements the maximal coverage location problem model and supports a range of solvers (e.g. glpk and lpSolve). It is not in a GIS environment.
2. Location-allocation analysis in ArcMap (though not open-source):http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/location-allocation.htm. This tool is part of the network analysis, so it only supports the modelling on road networks.
3. pyspatialopt package in Python: https://github.com/apulverizer/pyspatialopt. This is a library to create, solve, and analyze optimiation problems. Not in a GIS environment.

Other references:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSPvxgYKAFQ: an introduction to open source tools for spatial optimization.
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spatial_analysis_software: a list of spatial analysis software