# 1-center and k-center problem / maxmin facility problem in Post

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, routing, machine-learning

is there anybody who has already solved the 1- and k-center problem within PostGIS (optionally with distance metric obtained by pgrouting)?

References:

- [1-center problem in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-center_problem) and [graph center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_center) in Wikipedia
- [Facility location problem in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facility_location_problem)

What I did so far for the 1-center problem ([I found a similar solution elsewhere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89376/how-to-find-central-vertex-in-a-graph)) :

```
// Generate min. cost table for all pairs
INSERT into catchments 
SELECT  
    seq, id1 as source, id2 as target, cost 
FROM     
  pgr_apspWarshall('
    SELECT id, source, target, cost 
    FROM network WHERE city = ''New York''', false, false);

// Select max(min(distance))
SELECT source, max(cost) as maxcost 
FROM catchments 
WHERE cost <= 10 **km** GROUP BY source ORDER BY maxcost ASC;
```

However, the second step misses the initial choice.

**EDIT:** Someone has already asked a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9246/open-source-location-allocation-modelling) about OSS and location allocation which is a nearby topic. However, in the tools listed (Grass v.net.alloc)the functionality divides an area into districts based on predefined hubs/facilities/stations. To emphasize, I current question is about ab-initio optimization without previous definitions of location.

**EDIT2:** the Floyd-Warshall algorithm returns only the path information which has not previously been calculated- that is called dynamic programming in this sense.
Well, now the question remains how to reestablish the full information to run the 1-center problem?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the 2nd step misses the initial choice?

Comment: @JohnBarça, referring to the minimax facility location in Wikipedia, I think the point search for the point which minimizes max(min(distance)) is wrong. Summation over the max(min(distance)) could be a solution. I'll try later.

Comment: Actually, the ASCending order of maximum cost delivers a lot of nodes with zero or little costs. Investigating.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the 1-center problem can be solved using a tree algorithm like Dijkstra. 
I did not find any good way to reconstruct the complete tree using the much faster Floyd-Warshall algorithm (I think multiple self-joins are necessary).

However, the following code solves the problem. Nevertheless, using Dijktra (O(n^2)) we obtain a **complexity ~n^3**, which is quite costly (my motivation for Floyd's). Maybe another guy can ***come up with a faster idea***.

To achieve acceptable run times, I overlayed a **honeycomb structure** (grid) onto the network. Then I only calculated the distance matrix for the center nodes of each honeycomb.

```
// Generate min. cost table for all pairs
INSERT into catchments 
WITH nodes as (select source from network)
SELECT nodes.source, network.target,
  (SELECT sum(cost) FROM (
     SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('
       SELECT 
         id, source, target, cost
       FROM network',
       nodes.source, -- start node
       network.target, -- end node
       false,
       false)) AS foo ) AS cost
     FROM network, nodes;

// Select max(min(distance)) as center node
SELECT source, max(cost) as maxcost 
FROM catchments 
GROUP BY source ORDER BY maxcost ASC;
```

Honeycomb grids can be most easily achieved by using cartoDB functionality (github):

```
 CREATE VIEW hexagon_grid_250m AS
   SELECT row_number() OVER () AS id, the_geom FROM
   (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(geom, 250) as the_geom FROM city_area) AS hex,
   city_area AS a WHERE st_intersects(a.geom,hex.the_geom) = true
```

Select the nearest node in respect to the centroid of each honeycomb (only on PostGIS 2.2 + Postgreql 9.5):

```
SELECT grid.id, grid.the_geom, (SELECT n.the_geom
  FROM network AS n
  ORDER BY n.the_geom <-> st_centroid(grid.the_geom) LIMIT 1) AS nearest_node 
FROM 
  hex.hexagon_grid_250m AS grid
```

**I hope you'll like my idea and maybe come up with an improved one.**